# Get null array when using .net proxy to call a web service, but the xml response is OK

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using a third party XML SOAP web service, using svcutil.exe to generate the .net proxy class, but arrays not filled in the response object when invoking methods.

I used some network HTTP sniffer to get the XML response, i noticed that the arrays are OK in the XML, but they come null in the response object, i have tried to edit the WSDL file of the service to fix the problem but it didn't succeed.

EDIT:
Edited the WSDL and put it on my own host and added a service reference from VS but leaved the URL of the end-point to refer to the main third party service.

Can any one help me to make the correct change in the WSDL to meet the response that i get from the external web service?

The response XML i get using SmartSniff is:

```
.
.
.
.
<Summary>
    <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">1</ID>
    <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">AAA</Name>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Service xsi:type="xsd:string">Orders</Service>
            <Details xsi:type="xsd:string">Orders is not OK</Details></Error>
        <Error>
            <Service xsi:type="xsd:string">Details</Service>
            <Details xsi:type="xsd:string">The Details service was selected but but you do not have access to this service</Details>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
</Summary>
.
.
.
.
```

The WSDL is:

```
.
.
.
.
<element name="Summary" type="tns:SummaryPart" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
.
.
.
.
<complexType name="SummaryPart">
  <sequence>
    <element name="ID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="Errors" type="tns:ErrorArray" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="ErrorArray">
  <sequence>
    <element name="Error" type="tns:ErrorPart" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="ErrorPart">
  <sequence>
    <element name="Service" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="Details" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
.
.
.
.
```

I have these alternatives but didn't succeed:

1-

```
.
.
.
.
<element name="Summary" type="tns:SummaryPart" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
.
.
.
.
<complexType name="SummaryPart">
  <sequence>
    <element name="ID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="Errors" type="tns:Errors" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
**<complexType name="Errors">
  <sequence>
    <element name="Error" type="tns:Error" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="Error">
  <sequence>
    <element name="Service" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="Details" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>**
.
.
.
.
```

2-

```
.
.
.
.
<element name="Summary" type="tns:SummaryPart" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
.
.
.
.
<complexType name="SummaryPart">
  <sequence>
    <element name="ID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    **<element name="Errors" type="tns:Error" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>**
  </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="Error">
  <sequence>
    <element name="Service" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="Details" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
.
.
.
.
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can't "edit the wsdl" of another service and magically make the service return something different. Instead, handle what the service returns to you in whatever form it is, and then convert/cast/transform it into the type you need to use

Comment: Thanks, your are right i can't change what the service returns, but i can copy the WSDL and change it and put it on my host and add it as service reference but leave the URL to the main third party provider! i think it is legal trick, What u think!